# Simple question on conditional probabilities (multidimensional normal distributions)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ be two random vectors. We assume that $X\mid Y\sim\mathcal{N}(Y,\Sigma_X)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,\Sigma_Y)$

The goal is to sample from the distribution of $X$.

If we are given $Y$ then we can use $p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$, which is known.

If we are given some $x\in X$, then how can we do this sampling? I think that we need the marginal density $p_X(x)$, which should be given (using Bayes' rule) by

$$
p_X(x) = \frac{p_Y(y)}{p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)}p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y).
$$

If I am not mistaken, we need to find the ratio $\frac{p_Y(y)}{p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)}$.

Comment: You need to know joint distribution to answer that question. Marginals are not enough. (you could have $x=y$ or $x=-y$, for example).

Comment: Critics on notation: if $\mathbf{x}$ is a random variable then so is $p(\mathbf{x})$ so it does cannot denote a density. I would write $p(x)$ or $p_{\mathbf{x}}(x)$. In the same line I would write $\Sigma_{\mathbf{x}}$. An expression for conditional density can only be given if you have info about rv $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$. If there is independence then it equals the PDF of $\mathbb{y}$.

Comment: Thanks for your response @A.S. What if I assume that $\mathbf{y}$ is the mean vector of $\mathbf{x}$; that is, $\mathbf{y}=\bar{\mathbf{x}}$? Is there anything we can do now?

Comment: @drhab thanks for your comments. I just adopt the notation of bold-faced letters for vectors and capital letters for matrices. So, $p(\mathbf{x})$ isn't valid? I mean, the density of $\mathbf{x}$, as I write it above, isn't it meaningful?

Comment: You mean, $\mathbf y$ is deterministic? Then it has no PDF.

Comment: @Did, no I mean that the mean vector of $\mathbf{x}$ is itself a random vector $\mathbf{y}$ that is also distributed normally. (If you refer to my comment above)

Comment: Well. Everyone will understand what you mean by it, so don't take it too hard. But it is inconsistent for the reason given in my former comment: if $X$ is a random variable/vector and $f$ some suitable function then $f(X)$ is random too.

Comment: @drhab, I see your point. I will edit my answer soon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you assume that, then you can write $p(y|x)=\frac {p(y)p(x|y)}{p(x)}$ to get your desired answer. But $x$ might not be normal anymore.

Comment: Appended a mathematically correct version of the question, in the hope that this shows the defects of their version to the OP. Now remains the inconvenient fact that the question has no answer unless some additional hypothesis are made.

Comment: @Did, thanks for the edits. I further edited my question by adding another assumption; that is, $Y$ expresses the mean vector of $X$, hoping that this will make the problem feasible.

Comment: Sorry but "Assuming that $Y$ expresses the mean vector of $X$" does not solve the mystery. The mean vector of $X$ is a deterministic vector (denoted by $\mu_X$ in my rewriting). Once again, if $Y$ deterministic, then no PDF $p_Y$.

Comment: @Did, so can't we assume that the mean of $X$ is itself a random vector?

Comment: We could--but this would require a precise description of the way it is random, and the resulting random variable X might not be normal. // Do you actually have an idea of what you want to ask?

Comment: Maybe you could provide some context of your question? Like this it cannot be answered.

Comment: @Did I think he is trying to say $X|Y\sim N(Y,\sigma_x^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$ in the multivariate version,

Comment: @Did, exactly. That's what I want.

Comment: I just edited my question, trying to make it simple and correct, based on @Did 's comments.

Comment: "We want to find the density of $X\mid Y\sim\mathcal{N}(Y,\Sigma_X)$" Do you mean: *We want to find the density of $X$*? Asking, because the conditional density of $X\mid Y$ is given in the question...

Comment: @Did, really sorry for all this inconvenience. I edited my question again. Now, I describe the whole problem, but I may have mistakes (again). I'm not that familiarized with probabilities, so please don't shoot me! Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: If this is indeed the question, note that $Y=\mu_Y+Z$ and $X=Y+T$ where $Z$ and $T$ are independent, centered, normal, with respective variances $\Sigma_Y$ and $\Sigma_X$, hence $X=\mu_Y+Z+T$ is $\mathcal N(\mu_Y,\Sigma_X+\Sigma_Y)$.

Comment: To sum up (since the interpretation in my last comment seems to be correct), in the gaussian case, there are shortcuts to the general formula $$p_X(x)=\int p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)p_Y(y)dy.$$

Comment: Thank you very much @Did. This is what I want. Apologies for all the confusion.